# Secure way to insert and retrieve data to and from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I want to know some tips about PHP and MySQL.

When I get data from user then I use the following validation:

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
or
htmlentities()
or
trim()
```

Is it a secure way to get data from the user?

And what is the best way to retrieve data from Mysql database? I used `nl2br()`, but if i submit `I'm here` Then it shows `I\'m here`. It should be showing `I'm here`. I don't know what the correct method is.

Comment: Neither of these functions do validation. And whether it’s safe to use the output of these functions depend on how you use those values. So how do you use these functions?

Comment: Switch to PDO and please please please turn off magic quotes for the better of humanity.

Comment: @PeeHaa Thanks for this idea. But I think it's already OFF from php 5.0. is it?

Comment: @user1161867: No. Well, at least I had to turn it off manually on my installation. That was PHP 5.2.17 on Windows.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting data into a database, you'll use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string); not [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities). Or even better, MySQLi - or *even better*, [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

When you're outputting data from the database that might not be secure, you'll probably use `htmlentities` then.

To stop the slashes, [turn magic quotes off](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: Thanks @minitech. So htmlentities is secure? Any other method?

Comment: @user1161867: Yes, it's secure for HTML output. Just remember to use it. Oh, and there's also [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: @user1161867: You can mix them, but it's good to be consistent. And don't use both, things will break :)